# Getting only property definitions of entity in OData

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm

I am working on an app which requires communication with OData service (Microsoft Dynamics CRM to be exact). I have a requirement where I only need to know what all properties does the entity have.

e.g.

```
[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.1/contacts
```

returns all the contacts, however I want only property definitions of the contact.

Right now `[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.1/contacts` returns the JSON with values, however what I am looking is something schema of contacts entity. It should return me what all properties it has (e.g. `firstname`, `lastname`) and possibly the type of properties.

I tried using `$metadata` but without any luck. Is it possible to get information about entity only?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way to get an info about the entity is from the service metadata. 
Do you have an access to your metadata object inside your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers provided describe how to get the metadata for an entity, which technically **does** have all the definitions for a given entity.
However, when using the Web API an alternative would be to download the CSDL metadata document ($metadata) for the Web API and look for the definition of the contacts entityType. This is the data used to generate this documentation [contact EntityType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593097.aspx) and provides the specific definition used by the Web API.

You will see there are differences in the structure. i.e. metadata defines LookupAttributeMetadata attributes, but the Web API uses Single-valued navigation properties and read-only 'lookup properties'.

For information to understand the Web API $metadata, see [Web API types and operations > Entity types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607990.aspx#bkmk_entityTypes)

Answer (score 5):

See [Query Metadata using the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx).  The previous answer is close but you need the `$expand=Attributes` to get the list of Attributes.  Plus it gets all entities where you want to filter on Contact.

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions?$select=LogicalName&**$expand=Attributes($select=LogicalName)**&$filter=SchemaName eq 'Contact'
```

In the returned JSON you'll find the attributes at

```
value[0].Attributes
```

Which is an array.  In this case I `$select=LogicalName` so each one has the property LogicalName (as well as the MetadataId which is the GUID for that property).

So the first `$select` is for properties from the entities.
The `$expand` tells CRM to include the Attributes.  The inner `$select` tells which fields to return on the Attribute.  The `$filter` makes sure they only return all this metadata for Contact.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. Will award you bounty as soon as I am allowed to :-)

Comment: While this really helped me, I wanted to ask one more query. Currently I get all 270 properties, is there any way to get important properties or the properties that we can edit from the UI only?

Comment: You can retrieve the AttributeOf (api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions?$select=LogicalName&$expand=Attributes($select=LogicalName,AttributeOf)&$filter=SchemaName eq 'Contact') and exclude the fields where AttributeOf is not null.  These are logical columns (like the Name for a GUID field) and not actually stored on the table.  

For fields on the form, you would have to retrieve the form (SystemForm) for this entity:

/api/data/v8.1/systemforms?$select=formxml&$filter=objecttypecode eq 'contact' and type eq 2 and formactivationstate eq 1

This is a gross simplification because...

Comment: Different forms can be assigned to different users through security.  Multiple forms can apply to individual users.  But for out of the box CRM this should get you a single result.

Comment: You would then parse the XML (formxml) looking to cross reference datafieldname attributes of control nodes w/ the metadata fetched above.

Comment: Thanks @Benjy for help. Awarded you a bounty. This is good enough for me to start with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Web Api (looks like you are), then you can retrieve the `EntityMetadata` which has a navigation property for `AttributeMetadata`, which will describe attributes (aka; fields, properties).

`[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions`

[Use the Web API with CRM metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607833.aspx)

For example: `GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions?$select=DisplayName,IsKnowledgeManagementEnabled,EntitySetName&$filter=SchemaName eq 'Contact' HTTP/1.1`

Further examples at [Query Metadata using the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx)

Comment: I couldn't find navigation property when tried calling EntityDefinitions for "Contacts". Can you help me a bit with it?

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I tried doing that already. What I am trying to get is properties of that entity. e.g. Contacts has `firstname`, `lastname` properties. I want to get schema of that entity.